# rails 4 - active job - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) even though im passing 1 argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

Here I call the job - passing in procedure:

`ProcedureDayAfterJob.set(wait_until: reminder_for_jo).perform_later(procedure)`

Here is the job itself - taking procedure as argument:

```
class ProcedureDayAfterJob < ActiveJob::Base
 queue_as :mailers

 def perform(procedure)
    return if procedure.upcoming?


  Admin::NotificationMailer.procedure_day_after(procedure).deliver_later
 end
end
```

Here is method in mailer - taking procedure as argument:

```
def procedure_day_after(procedure)
  @procedure = procedure
  mail(
    # hiding who im sending to
  )
end
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
2017-12-15T19:25:57.365Z 9222 TID-oxvg7jsso ERROR: !!! ERROR HANDLER 
THREW AN ERROR !!!
2017-12-15T19:25:57.365Z 9222 TID-oxvg7jsso ERROR: wrong number of 
arguments (0 for 1)
2017-12-15T19:25:57.365Z 9222 TID-oxvg7jsso ERROR: 
/Users/foreverlabs/foreverlabs/app/jobs/procedure_day_after_job.rb:4:in 
`perform'
```

I'm passing in the argument to each method so can anybody figure out what's going on?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right line in the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this happen due to a typo in the initializer for the Service/Class being called within the job.

It is usually misleading with the single line errors where the only helpful info is the line number and file it is erroring on. With that, and looking at your queue log, it shows it is coming from the 4th line which is inside the perform method itself, and where the code has been redacted.

Check the class you are calling on this line to see if "initialize" is misspelled somehow (I do it from time to time myself),because doing such would cause the constructor to disable, as well as cause the class to expect zero arguments.

I'm sure you have fixed this, but hopefully this will help someone else in the future.